# Azure Error: The 'DB2OLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, .net, azure, db2

I am developing a `.NET` application that connects with `db2`. I am able to connect with the database locally, but when I deploy the same code in `Azure App Service`, I am facing:

> "The 'DB2OLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine"
> error."
>
> "ConnectionStrings": {
> "CONN_DB2": "Provider=DB2OLEDB;Network Address=*;Network Port=*;  Initial Catalog=*; Package Collection=*; User ID=* ;Password=*;"   }

The database resides on a different machine and I don't have any `db2` instance on my work station.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: The app needs to install the client driver for Db2. Have you done it?

Comment: @data_henrik No,iam quite new to db2 and not sure of how things gonna work ,can you please elaborate to understand better .Thanks!

Comment: Your app needs software to connect to Db2, it is called a driver. That software needs to be installed or available in the app service. Else it gives an error that the "provider" is not registered.

Comment: Install following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/db2oledbv/installing-data-provider-version-6-0

Comment: @jdweng i installed on local machine and working fine but after deploying in azure iam facing the issue

Comment: What is the connection string AZURE is using?  AZURE is a front end application for a database.  The provider has to be installed on the machine where AZURE is running.

Comment: @data_henrik ok but how come installing client drivers in local works in azure ,do i need to add client driver references in visual studio and i believe this is the download link of client drivers https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-initial-version-115-clients-and-drivers

Comment: @jdweng  "ConnectionStrings": { "CONN_DB2": "Provider=DB2OLEDB;Network Address=;Network Port=; Initial Catalog=; Package Collection=; User ID=* ;Password=*;" } this is the connection string iam using,and i am using windows server 2016 and azure in cloud not installed on machine ,in server locally  i downloaded db2oledb

Comment: The connection to database is made in the cloud.  It may take the connection string from the client, but AZURE is making the connection.

Comment: @jdweng sorry i did not get your point

Comment: What machine is AZURE cloud using?

Comment: windows server 2016 where i am developing .net application ,database reside in different machine